# Joins in hibernate

Tags: java, sql, sql-server-2008, hibernate

I'm using Java with Hibernate 3.

I have an sql as follows:

```
select sd3.id as id_3, sd2.id as id_2, sd1.id as id_1, od.id as id_0 from developer as sd3 
  left outer join developer as sd2 on sd3.sr_developer_id = sd2.id
  left outer join developer as sd1 on sd2.sr_developer_id = sd1.id
  left outer join developer as od on sd1.sr_developer_id = od.id
where sd3.id = 812
```

It is a case of self join.

The table structure looks like:

**developer**

```
id  | sr_developer_id
---------------------
812 | 463
463 | 8
8   | NULL
```

The output of the above query is:

```
id_3 | id_2 | id_1 | id_0
--------------------------
 812 |  463 |  8   | NULL
```

Now I want to convert this query either in HQL or in criteria.
Can anyone help me?

**EDIT :-**

**Developer.java**

```
private long id;
private long srDeveloperID;

public long getId() {
     return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
     this.id = id;
}

public long getSrDeveloperID() {
    return srDeveloperID;
}

public void setSrDeveloper(long srDeveloperID) {
    this.srDeveloperID = srDeveloperID;
}
```

**Developer.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping >
    <class name="com.beans.Developer" table="developer">
        <id name="id" column="id" type="long">
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>
        <property name="srDeveloperID" column="sr_developer_id" type="long"></property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: Can you please share your entity classes? They will help us help you.

Comment: @PrasadKharkar, please look at the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.....

put your query as it is(i.e select....................id=812) @ "Your Query";

```
{
     String sql = "Your Query";
     SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);

     query.setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);
     return query.list();
}
```

Comment: I've already done it. But I want only HQL or criteria. But thanks for the answer. +1 from my side.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve will be easier if you just map the association with Hibernate. So instead of:

```
<property name="srDeveloperID" column="sr_developer_id" type="long"></property>
```

do this:

```
<many-to-one name="seniorDeveloper" column="sr_developer_id" class="Developer"/>
```

And in **Developer.java**, instead of:

```
private long srDeveloperID;
```

this:

```
private Developer seniorDeveloper;
```

Then you can write your query as:

```
select sd3.id, sd2.id, sd1.id, od.id
from Developer sd3 
left join sd3.seniorDeveloper sd2
left join sd2.seniorDeveloper sd1
left join sd1.seniorDeveloper od
where sd3.id = 8
```

From this you can get a list of `Object[]`s, where the id's will be in `Object[0]`, `Object[1]` ..., so on.

Comment: I know this solution but the problem is that I cannot change POJOs as they're being used at many places & it will have a huge impact on the application. So I want to avoid this. But thanks for the answer. +1 from my side.